# Estimating the number of digits accuracy

Tags: numerical-methods

Suppose that solutions are computed to the linear system *Ax = b* where the entries of *A* have about 6 digits of accuracy, *b* has about 4 digits of accuracy. Given that the condition number of *A* is about $10^3$

How to estimate the number of digits of accuracy can be expected in the solution *x*.

Comment: Have you run across this? http://www.math.umd.edu/~petersd/460/linsysterrn.pdf

Comment: @MatthewConroy Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very good question. It could be phrased as How do we compute significant digits in our least squares results? An example is worked here: [What parameters can be used to tell a least squares fit is “well fit”?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249601/what-parameters-can-be-used-to-tell-a-least-squares-fit-is-well-fit/2252469#2252469)

In this case, the least squares solution vector is computed as
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 a_{0} \\
 a_{1} \\
\end{array}
\right]_{LS}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 4.8 \pm 4.9\\
 9.41 \pm 0.86 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
The uncertainties are built from the diagonal terms of the curvature matrix
$$
 \alpha = \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} \right)^{-1}.
$$